# Colouring geom_ribbon in ggplot2 & R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following line of code that draws two geom_ribbons to the same canvas to create a plot that looks like a geom_area, but one ribbon represents the data (like the geom_area does) and the other represents 100-data such that data + (100 - data) = 100. The code is:

```
customBars3 <- ggplot(barsFrame, aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(rAge)), y = PositivePercent)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = 100, ymin = PositivePercent, fill = "red")) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = PositivePercent, ymin = 0, fill = "green")) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Divergence)
```

and I get a graphic like the following:

[image]

However, I wanted the lower ribbon to actually be the colour green, and the upper ribbon to actually be the colour red. How do I do this and change the legend accordingly? My efforts to specify a fill colour results in the legend getting labelled with said colour but being filled in with different colours.

Thanks,
Ben.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `scale_fill_manual()` to change fill colors. First argument is your data level and second argument is actual color.

```
  +scale_fill_manual(values=c("green"="green","red"="red"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the parameter "fill" out of aes (I mean in the `geom_ribbon`) the corresponding ribbon will have the good color.